# sata to usb reader issues

Tags: backup, data-recovery

I have 2 laptops that are each running 10.04. One of these laptops got left out in the garage in the heat, shut itself down, and never restarted. There is only one file that I want off the laptop so I pulled the hd and hooked it to a reader on the computer running laptop. I've had no problems with any other hds that I have plugged into it until now.

I get the error

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
   need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I think you're going to need to get forensic here. It sounds like the drive is toast. There are [a variety of tools](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery#Extract_individual_files_from_recovered_image) available for this sort of stuff but before you start, given that the drive has likely already suffered some physical damage, do a full disk backup right now.

```
sudo apt-get install gddrescue
sudo ddrescue -n /dev/sdb diskbackup logfile
sudo ddrescue -d -r3 /dev/sdb diskbackup logfile
```

Then we need something like `foremost` or `photorec` to analyse and extract what it thinks are files.

```
# gets everything
sudo foremost -i diskbackup -o ~/recovery/

# gets .jpg files:
sudo foremost -i diskbackup -o ~/recovery/ -t jpg
```

Other options for -t include: `jpg`, `gif`, `png`, `bmp`, `avi`, `exe`, `mpg`, `wav`, `riff`, `wmv`, `mov`, `pdf`, `ole`, `doc`, `zip`, `rar`, `htm` and `cpp`.